# Speed up PostgreSQL logical decoding plugin

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I'm writing a new [logical decoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding-explanation.html) output plugin for PostgreSQL inspired by [`wal2json`](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json).  But mine produces JSON by using [SPI](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/spi.html) to repeatedly invoke [`to_json(...)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) on column values (instead of `wal2json`'s simpler JSON output that doesn't work well for some data types).

Testing shows that this is pretty CPU intensive.  Is there a way to achieve the same result with better performance?

Could you somehow directly invoke `row_to_json` on the tuple given to the change callback?

Is there a way to directly invoke `to_json` on each column value without SPI?

(My attempts to call those functions directly with `DirectFunctionCall1Coll` crashed the server, so any pointers are welcome!)

---

Here's what the functioning, but CPU-intensive, code looks like:

```c
spiArgType = columnInfo->atttypid;
/* Prepare the SQL */
spiPlan = SPI_prepare("SELECT to_json($1)::TEXT", 1, &spiArgType);
/* Execute it */
spiReturnValue = SPI_execute_plan(spiPlan, &columnValue, NULL, false, 1);
/* And if it succeeded, append to output string */
if (spiReturnValue < 0) {
    elog(ERROR, "SPI_execute_plan returned %d", spiReturnValue);
    appendStringInfo(out, "null");
} else {
  jsonDatum = SPI_getbinval(SPI_tuptable->vals[0], SPI_tuptable->tupdesc, 1, &isNull);
  appendStringInfo(out, "%s", TextDatumGetCString(jsonDatum));
}
SPI_freeplan(spiPlan);
```

---

A failed attempt using `OidFunctionCall1Coll`:

```c
TupleDesc cols = ...;
HeapTuple tuple = ...;
Form_pg_attribute colInfo;
Datum colValue;
bool isNull;

for (i=0; i < cols->natts; ++i) {
  colInfo = TupleDescAttr(cols, i);

  // (Omitted checks for dropped or system column)

  colValue = heap_getattr(tuple, i+1, cols, &isNull);
  if (! isNull) {
    // The following call fails, and emits this error:
    // ERROR:  could not determine input data type
    jsonDatum = OidFunctionCall1Coll(F_TO_JSON, InvalidOid, colValue);
    // This is never reached:
    appendStringInfo(out, "%s", TextDatumGetCString(jsonDatum));
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this comment from `fmgr.h`:

```
/* These are for invocation of a function identified by OID with a
 * directly-computed parameter list.  Note that neither arguments nor result
 * are allowed to be NULL.  These are essentially fmgr_info() followed by
 * FunctionCallN().  If the same function is to be invoked repeatedly, do the
 * fmgr_info() once and then use FunctionCallN().
 */

extern Datum OidFunctionCall0Coll ...
```

This should be way cheaper than SPI.

Comment: Hm, my naive attempt to use this approach fails and emits `ERROR: could not determine input data type`.  Poking at the PostgreSQL source, the `to_json` function [appears to need parse tree info](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_8/src/backend/utils/adt/json.c#L1916).  Is there a nice way to populate `FmgrInfo.fn_expr`?

Comment: That means that you didn't pass the argument properly. Hard to say more without seeing your code.

Comment: Yes, very possible I'm doing it wrong!  I edited the question to include (a shortened version of) my failed attempt.  However, I think [this post by Andrew Gierth from pgsql-hackers](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/87r23jxsck.fsf@news-spur.riddles.org.uk) describes the problem: the `to_json` function "needs the flinfo to get parameter type info."